# chrome extension get active tab id in browser action popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension supposed to catch any kind of redirections through a backgroud page, keep track of them for each tab, and outline them in a browser action for each tab.
Thus i want the action popup script to get the active tab's Id to display only datas related to this active tab in the action popup.

I already declared the permission "activeTab" in the manifest.

I tried `chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){})` before noticing in the documentation that the browser actions are mentionned as instance of contexts where `tab` is undefined. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent

I considered messaging a content script to get the tab id, but i did not find a suitable method to connect a content script and an action popup.

How could i get the active tab's ID in a browser action popup if it is possible ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need `tabs.query`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  var currTab = tabs[0];
  if (currTab) { // Sanity check
    /* do stuff */
  }
});
```

"Rare cases" <del>are mostly limited to a detached DevTools window being the current window</del> (looks like this case is fixed); should not happen during normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamically get active tab id**

```
function onUpdatedListener(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId.tabId, function(tab){
        console.log('New active tab: ' + tab.id);
    });
}
// Subscribe to tab events
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(onUpdatedListener);
// End tabs listeners-----------
```

Comment: a tab which is open as background tab, like with middle mouse click, is shown as active with your code, but it isn't.

Comment: I don't think this requires the inner function (ie, the `chrome.tabs.get` is not required). Just console.log the tabId from the outer function.