# Getting the current active tab in a Chrome extension - "currentWindow" vs "lastFocusedWindow"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The docs highlight this ([docs link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#current-window)):

> In the case of service workers, the value of the current window falls back to the last active window. Under some circumstances, there may be no current window for background pages.

**Question:** **What are the cases** for which the current window does not exist in an MV2 extension background page?

I have seen previous threads on this topic, for example: [one](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/gywzLNsOMVI), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451693/), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840655/2181238) (there are more). But all of them use `{ active: true, currentWindow: true }`, which seems incorrect, as per the docs above.

Moreover, there is a clearer named alternative - `{ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }` - and it is not suggested by any of the top answers.

**Question:**  If I want to get the currently active tab (that the user is interacting with), then is there any issue in using `lastFocusedWindow`? I'm only asking because again none of the top answers mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cases for which the **current window** does not exist [...]?

Per the [source code](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/extensions/chrome_extension_function_details.cc;l=58;drc=31fb07c05718d671d96c227855bfe97af9e3fb20) it may be absent in these cases:

1. while the browser starts so its window isn't yet open but the extension's background page is already started,
2. all of *this profile's* browser windows are closed (as extensions are scoped to the user profile), for example only incognito windows are open but the user didn't enable incognito access switch for this extension in chrome://extensions page,
3. during browser's shutdown.

> [...] is there any issue in using lastFocusedWindow [to get the currently active tab]?

In some cases, yes. For example in the action popup usually you'd want to interact with the window where the popup was shown and not with another window that the user switched to - although of course there may be an exception depending on what you do in the popup. Similarly, an extension page shown in a tab or in a side panel would typically want to handle its own window. A notable exception where you want the last focused window might be the case of showing your extension in a floating window popup to the side of the main browser window in an imitation of `chrome.sidePanel` for [older] browsers that don't have this API.

> all of them use { active: true, currentWindow: true }, which seems incorrect

It's correct because in the background script/worker context `currentWindow` intentionally acts the same as `lastFocusedWindow` as can be seen by clicking through the source code linked above until we arrive at the implementation that uses browsers_ordered_by_activation iterators in both cases ([last focused](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_api.cc;l=538-555) and [current](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/ui/browser_finder.cc;l=200-203;drc=31fb07c05718d671d96c227855bfe97af9e3fb20)).